# Bootstrap Switch check state doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

So I'm working on my usergroups page on my cms, and I added a switch to determine if the group has access to the admin section or not. If so (and the user checks the switch), a div of permissions will be displayed. For this, I used Bootstrap's plugin Bootstrap Switch.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input#isAdmin').bootstrapSwitch();
            $('#permissions_multi_select').multiSelect();
            $('#permissions_div').hide();

            $('input#isAdmin').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function() {
                if ($('input#isAdmin').state)
                    $('#permissions_div').show();
                else
                    $('#permissions_div').hide();
            });
        });
```

If I change the show() or hide() methods with an alert of $('input#isAdmin').state, or .attr('checked') or .checked, I get 'undefined'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$('input#isAdmin').state` with `$('input#isAdmin').bootstrapSwitch('state')` in the condition

```
$('input#isAdmin').bootstrapSwitch();
$('#permissions_multi_select').multiSelect();
$('#permissions_div').hide();

$('input#isAdmin').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function() {
    if ($('input#isAdmin').bootstrapSwitch('state'))
        $('#permissions_div').show();
    else
        $('#permissions_div').hide();
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o2y5mhpr/1/